# Is it normal to build a lot of bases in Subnautica?

Tags: subnautica

I am a new player of Subnautica and I find myself building a lot of bases. Already I have 4 bases and it looks like more are on the way. I seem to want to build them about 500m from each other, otherwise I have to travel long distances to get to things. However, if I start building bases every 500m, I am going to be building a LOT of bases eventually. Is this normal, or is there some way people are able to play the game with only a few bases?

Comment: I think you should play the game like you want to play it (hence my VTC as opinion-based).

Comment: Normal, especially when playing video games is very subjective. Why care if you are playing normal! Play however!

Comment: @Topcode Well, my concern is that I may be missing something and not doing something obvious that would allow the game to play without having to build so many bases. It's not a question about style.

Answer (score 1):

No. It certainly isn't a playstyle unheard of, but it's definitely non-standard.

For most players, one large base somewhere convenient, centrally on the map, and one smaller, at Lost River near Lava Zone, plus turning Cyclops into a mobile base, are a convenient, reasonable set. Occasional one-corridor or one-room outposts sure happen and can help with exploration. Benefits of more bases aren't big, while costs - especially time spent building them - are significant if you aim at finishing the game.

But on the other hand, many players, especially after first full playthrough, ignore the game goals and focus on self-appointed tasks. Building ludicrously big bases, building bases in wild locations (top of the Castle, the Abyss, under Aurora), or having scanner room coverage of the entire map, through plenty of small bases. Or whatever strikes their fancy - playing Subnautica as a sandbox game, not with a goal in mind.

So, it's not *wrong* as long as you enjoy it. It doesn't really help with finishing the game, but hey, finishing the game is only one of many ways one can play it.

Comment: Ok, if I do focus on a single big base in the center, what about the problem of traveling long distances? For example, the area that has the blood oil plants and the "Mountains" (where I am now) are both about 1000m away from central area, which I would estimate at being about 500m west of the starting location. So, that would mean I would have to travel 1000m if I wanted to collect blood oil.

Comment: @TylerDurden do you have any vehicles?

Comment: @Topcode I have a seamoth and a cyclops

Comment: @TylerDurden well, those pretty much eliminate travel time.

Comment: @Topcode Great majority of plants can be farmed in growth beds outside your base.